# how to bind grid structure in a loop in r

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, gridextra

I'm struggling with implementation of the function in flexible version. This first version is as follows:

```
plot9 <- function(d, b, clr) {  # d-object, b-index of category
  grid.newpage()
  return(
    grid.draw(rbind(
      cbind(ggplotGrob(hi9(d,b,clr[1])), ggplotGrob(hi9(d,b+1,clr[2])), ggplotGrob(hi9(d,b+2,clr[3]))),
      cbind(ggplotGrob(hi9(d,b+3,clr[4])), ggplotGrob(hi9(d,b+4,clr[5])), ggplotGrob(hi9(d,b+5,clr[6]))),
      cbind(ggplotGrob(hi9(d,b+6,clr[7])), ggplotGrob(hi9(d,b+7,clr[8])), ggplotGrob(hi9(d,b+8,clr[9])))
    ))
  )
}
```

and my loop version is:

```
 plotdem <- function(d, b, q) {  # d-object, b-index of category, q-quantity of graphs
    #r <- ifelse(q >= 3, 3, q)
    p <- q %% 3
    s <- as.integer(q/3)
    grid.newpage()
    return(
      for(j in 0:p) {
        grid.draw(rbind(
          for (i in 1:3) {
            cbind(ggplotGrob(hi9(d,b+i-1,0)))
          }
        ))
      } 
    )
  }
```

it is to plot graphs in a grid by simply calling: `plotdem(banks, 1, 3)`. No matter the arguments and nested function. My issue is to properly use `rbind` and `cbind` in those loops. Now the result si `NULL`. The purpose of this function is to plot even one graph, or if b=3 plot 3 in a row, then, if b=4 plot one below in next row. So the first function works ok. and plots 3x3 graphs.

By the way, to make this stick I must use both `library(gridExtra)` and `library(grid)` and of course `ggplot2`.

Comment: You may want to create a gtable first then assign grobs in the right place, rather than using c/rbind multiple times.

Comment: Ok, thanks for hint. So I'll try to do it this way with hope that this type-sensitive ggplot's objects will do the job.

Comment: Actually if you want to align plots you're better off with c/rbind. I just have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yesterday I dug the net to find the solution to plot histograms in grid and this was the only working solutions. Other working solutions failed with my data and approach, so I need to keep this way, because it works. Maybe in the meantime I'll find some other way.